# Python Pandas multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm try create table like in example:
[Example_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpClf.png)

My code:

```
data = list(range(39)) # mockup for 39 values

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1', '2', '6'], [str(year) for year in range(2007, 2020)]],
                                     names=['Factor', 'Year'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['World'], columns=columns)

print(df)
```

But i get error:

> Shape of passed values is (39, 1), indices imply (1, 39)

What i'm did wrong?

Comment: You already asked this question and I think I already indicated that without a reproducible example of the data it will be difficult to know what's going on. Please provide a sample `data_dict`

Comment: data is just list " [18183059018.027966, 16868527277.51174, 18331809529.53519, 19724006864.797657... " which consists of 39 elements. This list plays the role of data in the table to which 39 elements need to be passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the `data` in a list to force the DataFrame constructor to interpret the list as a row:

```
data = list(range(39))

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1', '2', '6'],
                                      [str(year) for year in range(2007, 2020)]],
                                     names=['Factor', 'Year'])
df = pd.DataFrame([data], index=['World'], columns=columns)
```

output:

```
Factor    1                                                                2                                                                6                                                            
Year   2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
World     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38
```